# Adding duplicate values to original value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 6 column fields. if there is a duplicate email, then select the newer record based on dates in second column and take all data from that row except column F (6th column) in Column F combine the values in all the records
so for example if there is

These two lines of data should be combined:

```
s@s.com 15/12/2012 122 dd34 23ds3 This data
s@s.com 12/12/2012 123 dd35 232d2 Should be combined
```

The result should be:

```
s@s.com 15/12/2012 122 dd34 23ds3 This data Should be combined
```

Comment: Please provide clear example.

Comment: And your question is "How do I do this?" "Can I do this with just queries?" "How do I get records with duplicate values?" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  email, date, column_c, column_d, column_e,
  GROUP_CONCAT(column_f SEPARATOR ' ') AS column_f
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM tablename
  ORDER BY date
) i
GROUP BY email
  HAVING date = MAX(date)
```

[See it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee47c/4)

Comment: add "ORDER BY date" to the >>>> GROUP_CONCAT too NOT THE QUERY :-)

Comment: Not necessary within the bounds of the specification of the question but agreed it's probably an idea, will edit.

Comment: There could be 3 entries when the script is executed. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @Waygood I'm setting up an SQLFiddle to demonstrate what will actually happen with some "real" data

Comment: Dont forget to put the dates in random order, to simulate delete insert on the table :) I also edited it to remove the order from the end and put it in the GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @Waygood OK, now [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee47c/2) I was not expecting. Where did `d@d.com` go? :S

Comment: @Waygood Oh... wait. I know where it went. And you were right about the `ORDER BY`, I just put it in the wrong place. See edit above for actual solution that gets all results. `HAVING` always, without fail, screws me over, and I never ever seem to remember that it doesn't work exactly like I'm expecting it to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good work. But still pbm persists. I am getting only few records. And some more records missing. Any help to all records except duplicates and want to be above question.

Comment: @balamurugan Can you provide a larger sample data set please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still missing data, I would try the following... My pre-query is getting each email with their latest date.  THEN, join to the test table to get the details of ONLY the "First Record" by date per email...  Then join all other records by email and get the group concat.

```
select
      FirstRec.Email,
      FirstRec.Date,
      FirstRec.Column_C,
      FirstRec.Column_D,
      FirstRec.Column_E,
      GROUP_CONCAT( BySameEmail.Column_F SEPARATOR ' ' ) as Column_F
   from
      ( select
              email, max( date ) Newest
           from
              test_Table
           group by 
              email ) PQ
         JOIN Test_Table FirstRec
            on PQ.EMail = FirstRec.EMail
           AND PQ.Newest = FirstRec.Date
         JOIN Test_Table BySameEMail
            on PQ.EMail = BySameEMail.EMail
   group by
      FirstRec.EMail
```

I was getting all 3 emails from the SQL Fiddle sample data provided by Dave's answer posting.